# Reading a webpage using lxml and xpath

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml, urllib2

I'm trying to get the latest prices for some of the markets from PredictIt.  For example, the "Will Donald Trump win the 2016 Republican presidential nomination?" market found at https://www.predictit.org/contract/838/ I specifically want the text that will be "**Latest Price: ??**"

Chrome tells me that the xpath is /html/body/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[2]/p[1]/strong/text()

```
import urllib2
url = 'https://www.predictit.org/Contract/838/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
date = page.read()

from lxml import html
etree = html.fromstring(data)
price = etree.xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[2]/p[1]/strong/text()')
```

Everything seems ok, but

```
 print price
```

returns an empty list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you can rely on the string `'Latest Price'` being inside a `<strong>` tag, then you could use:

```
In [305]: root.xpath('//strong[contains(text(), "Latest Price:")]/text()')
Out[305]: ['Latest Price: 34']
```

Or, perhaps more robustly, you could search all `<p>` tags *and their descendants* for text which includes the string `'Latest Price'`:

```
In [312]: root.xpath('//p/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(), "Latest Price")]/text()')
Out[312]: ['Latest Price: 34']
```

---

```
import urllib2
url = 'https://www.predictit.org/Contract/838/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = page.read()

import lxml.html as LH
root = LH.fromstring(data)
price = None
for text in root.xpath('//p/descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(), "Latest Price:")]/text()'):
    price = float(text.split(':', 1)[-1])

print(price)
# 35
```

---

The reason why the XPath `/html/body/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[2]/p[1]/strong/text()` may be failing is because the HTML received from `urllib2.urlopen(url).read()` may be different than the HTML received by Chrome. Chrome's browser processes JavaScript which may change the DOM. `urllib2` does not process JavaScript. If you needed the DOM after executing JavaScript, then you would need an automated browser like Selenium instead of `urllib2`. Happily in this case, the content you are looking for is not supplied by JavaScript. However, an overly specific XPath such as `/html/body/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[2]/p[1]/strong/text()` may trip you up.

Using the HTML returned by `urllib2`, there appear to be only 6 `<div>` tags:

```
In [315]: root.xpath('/html/body/div')
Out[315]: 
[<Element div at 0x7f0bd63632b8>,
 <Element div at 0x7f0bd6363310>,
 <Element div at 0x7f0bd6363368>,
 <Element div at 0x7f0bd63633c0>,
 <Element div at 0x7f0bd6363418>,
 <Element div at 0x7f0bd6363470>]
```

Trying to access the 7th `<div>` tag yields an empty list:

```
In [316]: root.xpath('/html/body/div[7]')
Out[316]: []
```